# selenium webdriver - close all child window except one particular child window using foreach (java)

Tags: eclipse, selenium

1. Launch popuptest.com
2. Click 'Multi-PopUp Test #2 '
3. Print the number of windows opened
4. Close all the windows but not the parent window and the child window which has background color "#00C957"
5. Print the page URL and Title and the closed windows
6. Take the snapshot of the windows which are open.

Please any one help me in coding:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path + chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://popuptest.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        String parentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
        System.out.println("Parent Window Session ID :" +parentWindow);
        driver.findElementByLinkText("Multi-PopUp Test #2").click();

        Set<String> allHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
        System.out.println("Get All Windows :" +allHandles.size());
        for (String window: allHandles) {
        driver.switchTo().window(window);
        WebElement popwindow = driver.findElementByXPath("//body[@bgcolor='#00C957']");
          if(!window.equals(popwindow))
            {
            driver.close(); 
            System.out.println("Get Title" +driver.getTitle());
            System.out.println("Get Current URl" +driver.getCurrentUrl());*/
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is working perfectly.

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Pop_up_Child_Window_pop_up_example_4 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://popuptest.com/popuptest12.html");

        Set<String> windowIDs = driver.getWindowHandles();
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        System.out.println("number of windows opened --> "+ windowIDs.size());

        Iterator<String> it = windowIDs.iterator();
        String parent  = it.next();

        // child pop 1
        String child  = it.next();
        driver.switchTo().window(child);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        WebElement attri = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body[@bgcolor='#3D59AB']"));
        String bgOfChild = attri.getAttribute("bgcolor");
        System.out.println(bgOfChild);
        if(!bgOfChild.equals("#FF6633"))
        {
            driver.close();
        }

        // child pop 2
        String child2  = it.next();
        driver.switchTo().window(child2);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        WebElement attri2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body[@bgcolor='#FF6633']"));
        String bgOfChild2 = attri2.getAttribute("bgcolor");
        System.out.println(bgOfChild2);
        if(!bgOfChild2.equals("#FF6633"))
        {
            driver.close();
        }

        // child pop 3
        String child3  = it.next();
        driver.switchTo().window(child3);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        WebElement attri3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body[@bgcolor='#00C957']"));
        String bgOfChild3 = attri3.getAttribute("bgcolor");
        System.out.println(bgOfChild3);
        if(!bgOfChild3.equals("#FF6633"))
        {
            driver.close();
        }

    }

}
```